# Oak processionary or what else?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

We have those caterpillars with some sort of webbing on stinging nettles below some oaks.  Photographs I found in Wikipedia look quite hairier with long white hairs but maybe it's the molting level?

Or those guys are something less notorious.  This is in Germany, Northrhine-Westfalia.

[image: Caterpillars on stinging nettles]

And [here is a video](https://youtu.be/kC21Mduw6ZQ) in case it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Looks more like aglais io, the European peacock.  At any rate, oak and stinging nettle leaves are quite too dissimilar to make a crossover of comparatively specialized caterpillars likely.

Comment: Totally agreed!